# How to protect a java code easily from reverse enginnering?

Tags: reverse-engineering, obfuscation

i have programmed a library in java i want to protect from reverse engineering.
I read about obfuscation and understood that it is only making it a little more difficult to read instead of making it completely impossible to decompile.

Iam not very expierenced in it-security/ software protection.

I found [ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard)  a free tool for java/ android obfuscation.
I have tried different ways to obfsucate the jar file. My problem and also question is, can i actually import a jar file in to a different project after obfuscation?? 
My library was not working anymore as i imported it in a project.

Do i have to obfusacate the whole java application at the end? or can i obfuscate my library i want to protect and use it in different projects?

Comment: You cannot make the code impossible to decompile, only harder to read once it has been decompiled

Comment: A typical approach to prevent people from copying your work is by making it *illegal* using copyright law or NDA's, instead of trying to make it impossible through technical means.